# How to Prevent Session Timeout in Login Component in constructor using NgIdleKeepaliveModule

Tags: angular

I am calling Timeout session method in `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts` with router condition not equals login but this fails. The problem is Timeout session appears in Login Page and fails to do `idle.stop()`

Here is my code :

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.subscription=this._router.events
  .filter((e => e instanceof ActivationEnd)).subscribe((e) => 
  {
    if(this._router.url.indexOf('login')<0){
      this.sessionTimeout(this._router,this.idle,this.keepalive,this.ngbModal);
    }
  });
}

sessionTimeout( _router:Router,idle: Idle,  keepalive: Keepalive,ngbModal: NgbModal) {

  // method here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the router URL condition inside constructor and this will prevent the session Timeout in Login Component.

The below code might help you if you are trying to achieve this inside constructor in app.component.ts

```
constructor(private router:Router,private element: ElementRef, private idle: Idle, 
            private keepalive: Keepalive, private ngbModal: NgbModal)
  {
    idle.setIdle(900);
    idle.setTimeout(300);
    idle.setInterrupts([new EventTargetInterruptSource(
        this.element.nativeElement, 'keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown 
        touchstart touchmove scroll')]);

    idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = 'NO_LONGER_IDLE';
    });

    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = 'TIMED_OUT';
      this.timedOut = true;
    });

    idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = 'IDLE_START'
    });

    idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown: any) => {
      //subscribe code here
    });
    keepalive.interval(15);

  //to prevent login component from timeout session
  router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    if(this.router.url.search(/login/) == -1){
        idle.watch();
       }
    else{
        idle.stop();
    }
   });  
    this.reset();
 }
```

Comment: Adding router condition inside constructor works for me.